# Generate final release apk

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to release the final apk from a react native project but I can't run this on any device.

It says:

```
Can't find variable __fbBatchedBridge
```

I try using `gradlew assembleRelease` and also downloading bundle to asset folder

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if you have react Gradle file in your Gradle files. Try bundling the asset manually if you do not have this file.

Comment: I bundle the asset manually with this: `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"` but problem persists